# Synchronous video playback on multiple devices

Tags: sync, video, automation, media-player

I have multiple Android-based projectors (Xiaomi 4k) and want them to start playback of a movie file at the same time. It's not the same file on each device, so casting wouldn't work. What I need is to somehow be able to send the "play" command to all of the devices simultaneously. I also need to be able to schedule these "play" commands, so they are triggered automatically during the day.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restrictions on apps only. Meanwhile, due to the original wording, I migrated this question to our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87894/520). Feel free to visit and join their site to regain ownership of your question there.